# Welcher Tag ist der nächste Dienstag?

Tags: regional, time

Keeping in mind that today is Saturday 05/28/2011, a German says

> Gut. Treffen wir uns also am nächsten
>   Dienstag um acht Uhr.

What should you do, so as not to miss the appointment?

---

Wenn heute Samstag, der 28.05.2001 ist
und ein Deutscher fragt

> Gut. Treffen wir uns also am nächsten
>   Dienstag um acht Uhr.

was machst du als nächstes, wenn du sichergehen willst den Termin nicht zu verpassen?

**Edit:**

The answer depends on region and when coworkers not aware of this fact make appointments, they can mean different days. Please add the region to your answer.

I grew up in Frankfurt/Main and my parents are from East Prussia.

For more than 30 years I believed, that all German use **dieser** vor the next coming and **nächster** for the following.

I tend to ask for the date (Datum) to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Nächster oder kommender Dienstag?

Comment: Machst du einen Unterschied zwischen nächstem und kommendem Dienstag? Ich Unterscheide zwischen diesem und nächstem Dienstag.

Comment: Ich nicht, aber einige Leute mit denen ich zu tun hab.

Comment: “What are you going to do next” – I ask to be sure which Tuesday it is <_< Seriously, I hate this ambiguity a lot :D (although I would always assume the next Tuesday, i.e. the 31st)

Comment: although I'm a german-teachers child the only thing I can do to get over this regional problem is to get out my cell phone and write every appointment down reassuring the date by number.

Comment: Given the American pattern `05/28/2011` things don’t get less confusing a few days later…

Comment: I think that "Dieser Dienstag" can only be used on Tuesday. "Nächster Dienstag" means tomorrow, if the current day is Monday.

Comment: 'Dieser Dienstag' kann 'Dienstag dieser Woche' bedeuten, aber natürlich schlecht am Samstag zuvor, weil dann ist es ja der Dienstag nächster Woche. Samstags ist 'dieser Dienstag' schon ein paar Tage her. "Dieser Mai war heißer als alle Mais der letzten 10 Jahre." "Der nächste Juni wird wieder viele Miniermotten bringen." "Dieser Juni?" "Nein, der Juni nächsten Jahres - dieser Juni läuft ja schon, und ist nicht mehr nächster Juni"

Comment: Andere Sprachen haben genau das gleiche Problem: [Englisch](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841), [Französisch](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1398).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A common usage is to distinguish between "this Tuesday" (the chronological next one) and "next Tuesday" (the Tuesday after this). But many people will also use "next Tuesday" for the chronological next one due to the literal meaning of "next".

Personally, I always check with the actual date.

Comment: I even found confusions in the same regions, so I wouldn't even be sure it's region-specific.

Comment: If you don't talk about this Tuesday, this Tuesday is next Tuesday. Only if you talk about this Tuesday, then next Thuesday may refer to the Tuesday next to this Tuesday, as you can talk about the Tuesday next to the 2nd Tuesday of November (which is, btw. the 3rd Tuesday) in November.

Comment: @user : first rule of Tuesday: don't talk about Tuesday!

Comment: I'll usually go for "Wir treffen uns Freitag" or "Wir treffen uns nächste Woche Freitag" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6):

This seem *very simple*:

- *Nächst* is the **superlative of *nah*** (close by) <sup>[wiktionary: nah](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nah)</sup>.
  It follows that "der Nächste" is *"the nearest"*

  *The [...]day that most closely follows today.*

Though of course It may be that it's misused a lot (I never noticed).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether I understand the question correctly but here I go.

Personally I think there isn't a lot of ambiguity when you refer to a day by name that doesn't occur in the current week anymore. So in this example it would be the 31st.

On the other hand, if today is say Monday and you say "nächsten Mittwoch", it could mean the day after tomorrow or Wednesday next week. Some people make a difference between "diesen Mittwoch" and "nächsten Mittwoch". It's better to ask if you're not sure.

Comment: +1 Asking is the correct answer. Personally I'm using 'dieser' and 'nächster' and using my parents conventions I mean Jun 7. But I know that a my workplace Munich the local people use it for 31st May.

Answer (score 4):

In Swabia (south west) the terms *diesen* or *nächsten* is not generally used in the local dialects.

The dates would be communicated as follows:

> "Wir treffen uns am Dienstag", means the next closest day.
>
> "Wir treffen uns am Dienstag darauf", is a week later.

Answer (score 4):

Ich kenne ebenfalls die schon genannte Unterscheidung zwischen 'diesem Dienstag' (der nächstmögliche) und 'nächstem Dienstag' (Dienstag der auf diese Woche folgenden Woche).

Es gibt wohl eine Tendenz zur regionalen Aufteilung, die ist aber auch nicht eindeutig. Siehe 
http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_7/f11a/

Comment: Guter Link. Wirklich erstaunlich, dass man das Problem manchmal erst sehr spät wahrnimmt.

Answer (score 3):

I always get confused with that, too. I would naturally mean the 31st. But to be sure, you can ask

> Also den jetzt kommenden Dienstag?

Actually if I wanted to mean the 31st, I would only say

> Gut. Treffen wir uns also dann am Dienstag um acht Uhr.

But people do that differently, so I also think the German meant the 31st but you can ask to be sure.

**Edit:** My parents come from Berlin, I grew up in Rostock. I actually use "dieser", "kommender", and "nächste" all for the same meaning and say something like "Dienstag in anderthalb Wochen" to refer to June 7th.

Answer (score 3):

This might be different from region to region, but where I come from (Rheinland) I usually found the following meaning:

**"Diesen Dienstag"** means the Tuesday within the current week. So if my reference date is `Mo, 30.05.2011` "diesen Dienstag" means `Di, 31.05.2011`. **"Nächsten Dienstag"** is therefore short for "tuesday next week" which means `Di, 07.06.2011`.

However: Even for the same group of people this seems to vary from time to time, so I always specify it like "Diese Woche Dienstag" or "Nächste Woche Dienstag" to be absolutely clear.

Comment: I disagree. 'Nächster Montag' is always the same as 'dieser Montag', just if you say 'nicht diesen Montag, sondern nächsten' the 'übernächster Montag' is meant, which is the next, seen from this monday. You may even say: 'Not the 2nd monday in October, but the next' which is the 3rd monday in October, not the first in June.

Answer (score 2):

If I want be clear about it, I tend to say

> am Dienstag

for the very next Tuesday, and

> Dienstag in acht Tagen

for the Tuesday which is at least one week/eight days away from now (counting the current day as well).

The Tuesday after that one is said to be *in vierzehn Tagen* (which would be equivalent to *quinze jours*/15 days in French) so the counting is a bit weird…

Answer (score 2):

One of the best questions on here, and one that I fear will remain unanswered, since there doesn't seem to exist a consensus.

To try and be as specific as possible oneself, one could adopt the usage of "*Dienstag nächster Woche*" and "*diesen Dienstag*".

Also keep in mind that in Germany, the week starts on monday. Apparently, some countries wrongly appoint sunday to be the first day of the week, even though sunday is clearly part of the week-*end* ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Switzerland there are confusions indeed:

If I say 'Nächschte Donnschti' (next Thursday) on Monday, I mean the day three days from now. But some of my friends would understand three days and a week from now and they'd tell me that if I ment 'dä Donnschti' (this Thursday) why did I say 'nächschte'. But if the same conversation would take place on Saturday, 'nächschte' would be fine for them.

Answer (score -2):

Es gibt überhaupt keinen Zweifel, dass dieser Sonntag der nächste Sonntag ist, denn heute ist Samstag, und die Woche beginnt in Westeuropa genormt montags.

Was hat es mit der Woche zu tun? Nun, es gibt den Sonntag nächster Woche, der eben nicht dieser oder nächster Sonntag ist.

Wenn Montag wäre, dann könnte man behaupten, der nächste Sonntag sei der dann vergangene Sonntag (-1 Tag ist näher als +6 Tage), aber da der letzte Sonntag nicht wiederkommt ist die Nähe im Kalender nicht ausschlaggebend, von einem nächsten zu sprechen.

Wer die Gesprächspartner nicht mit Besserwisserei vor den Kopf stoßen will, der fragt also höflich nach 'Morgen, oder Sonntag nächster Woche?'.

Der Irrtum entsteht aus der Kombination mit der Nennung eines anderen Datums, von dem aus gesehen es der nächste Sonntag sein wird. Wenn ich sage 'nicht dieser Sonntag, sondern der nächste', so bezieht sich das 'der nächste Sonntag' nicht mehr auf heute, sondern auf diesen Sonntag. Von diesem Sonntag aus der nächste Sonntag ist von heute aus der übernächste Sonntag. Ich kann auch sagen 'Nicht der 2. Sonntag im Oktober, sondern der nächste', was der dritte Sonntag im Oktober ist, nicht der erste im Juno. :)

Comment: Ihr könnt meine Antwort gerne abwerten, aber wenn Ihr Eure Argumente nicht zur Diskussion stellt, dann kann ich sie nicht widerlegen, und Ihr bleibt auf Euren falschen Ansichten leider sitzen.

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort gut.