# "nächstes Wochenende" does it mean upcoming or after next?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Sometimes I get confused about this in English too. If someone says "nächstes Wochenende," does it normally mean the upcoming weekend, or the one coming after that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Welcher Tag ist der nächste Dienstag?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/541/welcher-tag-ist-der-n%c3%a4chste-dienstag)

Comment: This is further complicated by existence of the term *kommendes Wochenende*, which does not seem to be mentioned by the existing answers.

Comment: @guidot The question is about *nächstes Wochenende*. *Kommendes Wochenende* is very clear and doesn't make it more complicated.

Comment: @Olafant: While I agree that the meaning of *kommendes Wochende* is clear, it creates ambiguity. Whoever uses it, is likely to assume *nächstes Wochenende* to mean a different one (the one after *kommendes*).

Comment: @guidot What about *kommenden Dienstag*? Imo it's the same question and should be discussed there.

Comment: @guidot, im letzten Absatz erwähne ich doch _kommendes Wochenende_. Ich nehme an, sie haben es einfach versehentlich überlesen ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Confusing as it may sound, this differs between regions or even between families within a region.

For example, I (and members of my family) would say:

> Dieses Wochenende waren wir im Zoo, nächstes Wochenende gehen wir ins Kino, und übernächstes Wochenende fahren wir ans Meer.
>   
>   <sub>(dieses — **heute** — nächstes — übernächstes)</sub>

So, for me *nächstes Wochenende* is usually the upcoming weekend. By contrast, my friend (and members of his family) would say:

> Voriges Wochenende waren wir im Zoo, dieses Wochenende gehen wir ins Kino, und nächstes Wochenende fahren wir ans Meer.
>   
>   <sub>(voriges — **heute** — dieses — nächstes)</sub>

So, for him *nächstes Wochenende* is the weekend after the upcoming one.

We have very often argued about this misunderstanding, and meanwhile, I usually say *kommendes Wochenende* to make clear that I refer to the upcoming weekend. But still we often get confused when someone talkes of *dies Wochenende*.

Comment: Thank you, getting an understanding of the contextual/regional differences is very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

That's a tough question because even Germans are split about this. As a rough guide, the upcoming weekend might be called "nächstes Wochenende" if the past weekend is just over (e.g. on Mondays and Tuesdays) and "dieses Wochenende" if the upcoming one is just around the corner (e.g. on Thursdays and Fridays). In that case "nächstes Wochenende" refers to the weekend after the upcoming one.

Confusing? Germans confuse each other all the time. So it's a good solution to add the date after "dieses/nächstes Wochenende" (e.g. "dieses Wochenende am 19./20.").

Answer (score 3):

For me, the meaning of "Dieses Wochenende" depends on the context (on the current day of the week): it is the last weekend on Mo+Tu and the upcoming one on Th+Fr.

But however you understand "dieses Wochenende" yourself, you can most of the time differentiate these meanings, as you will use "Perfekt/Präteritum" for the last one and "Präsens/Futur" for the upcoming one:

Dieses Wochenende war ich... -> the last one

Dieses Wochenende gehe ich... -> the upcoming one

"Nächstes Wochende (WE)" on the other hand, will for me always be the upcoming one, which of course means that "diese WE" and "nächstes WE" are the same when around Th+Fr.